# Perpendicular offset to a surface (triangular mesh)

Tags: geometry, offset, mesh, surface

I need to make a perpendicular (not vertical) offset to a surface. The surface is represented as Triangular Irregular Network (TIN, MESH). The condition is that triangle before and after the offset should be parallel, i.e., slope/aspect should be preserved.

Could anyone point me to algorithms/articles/ or any clues?

Comment: Do you have to avoid self-intersections? This would make the algorithm a lot more complicated. Otherwise it's basic vector algebra. If the surfaces are relatively smooth and the offset is small, it could be that self-intersections are not an issue. Also if the surface is convex in your offset direction.

Comment: @Frank Puffer, yes self-intersection (overlaps) and gaps should be avoided. That's right seems to be complicated. I came across multiple vertex normals used in machine control but seems not easy to implement.